# Outlook.Interop - Checking if a folder is hidden

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have an odd problem. I have an application that allows a user to select folders from their Outlook mailboxes/stores, and it's supposed to skip over any folders that are hidden.

To accomplish this, I perform the following check on the folder:

```
try
{
  if (folder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"))
  {
    // Yes, it's a hidden folder
    return true;
  }
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comex)
{
  // If the hidden property doesn't exist at all, we'll get a COM exception
  // here, which is fine.
  return false;
}
catch (Exception)
{
  // Some other failure
  throw;
}
```

Now, on my test machine, this works perfectly fine. I use MFCMAPI to toggle on/off the hidden attribute, and the application responds appropriately.

On another remote user's machine, ALL of their folders are showing up, even the normally-hidden ones like Quick Step Settings.

I turned up the logging and in the COMException catch() block, I end up seeing things like this:

```
Checking to see if Quick Step Settings is hidden: NOT HIDDEN
COMException: The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B" is unknown or cannot be found.
```

But I walked the user through examining that folder's properties via MFCMAPI and I took screenshots that show that the folder DOES have that hidden flag set to true. So I'm not sure why the application can't see that property...?

[image: MFCMAPI screen capture of the folder flags]

The user does make use of mailboxes that are online-only mailbox stores / shared mailboxes, so I'm wondering if there's maybe a different namespace for the property or something under certain circumstances? Can anyone weight in here?

Comment: The prop tag will be the same. Is the user looking at the folder from the right store? Do they see the same value in OutlookSpy if they click IMAPIFolder button?

Comment: Yep, I've double-checked the store selection and the folder selection. The code actually loops through all folders, and ALL of them come back with that property missing, even though MFCMAPI shows otherwise. 

Incidentally, a completely different mailbox within the same user's profile doesn't seem to have a problem.